# Crystal Reports: Building a complicated record selection

Tags: crystal-reports, record, sql-view, formula-editor

I have been put in charge of developing an inventory snapshot report that is divided by two types: Orders and Stock.  In addition to this, only items with a specific status should show on the report.

```
I have a parameter that is used to determine the specific date for the report. {?endDate}
I have a field in a view that pulls the date the item was received. {rec_date}
I have a formula field that pulls the group (orders/stock) -- {@grouping}
I have a formula field that pulls the status -- {@state}
```

Essentially what I need in the record selection is:

```
( @grouping = "Orders" and rec_date < {?endDate} and @state in (0,2,5) )

OR

( @grouping = "Stock" and rec_date < {?endDate} and @state in (1,2,3,5,7) )
```

Any way I have been trying to write this has been invalid.  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Invalid how?  What error are you getting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your formulas must be in squiggly brackets as well:

```
( {@grouping} = "Orders" and rec_date < {?endDate} and {@state} in [0,2,5] )

OR

( {@grouping} = "Stock" and rec_date < {?endDate} and {@state} in [1,2,3,5,7] )
```

Comment: You're syntax is almost correct.  Array values need to be contained in square brackets ([]) in the record-selection formula.

Comment: Thanks @craig, I was just testing that out now and noticed that. I never remember the array syntax :P

Comment: Thank you, I couldn't find any easily reference-able documentation on that syntax.  I could find a million seminars and products about it though.

Comment: If you use formula fields (e.g. `{@state} in [0.2.5]`) in the record-selection formula, most likely the filter will be applied while reading records (records are included/excluded as they are returned from the database).  If possible, test against a database field (e.g. `{table.state} IN [0,2,5]`) or against a SQL Expression (e.g. `{%state} IN [02,5]`); these clauses will be sent to the database for processing.  The performance boost will be significant.